# Large volume of scheduled messages seem to get stuck on ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using Apache ArtemisMQ 2.17.0 to store a few million scheduled messages. Due to the volume of messages **paging** is
triggered and almost half of the messages are stored on shared filesystem  (master-slave shared filesystem store (NFSv4) ha topology).
These messages are scheduled every X hours and each "batch" is around 500k messages with the size of each individual
message a bit larger than 1KB.

In essence my use case dictates at some point near midnight to produce 4-5 million of messages which are scheduled to leave next day as bunches in predefined scheduled periods (e.g. 11a.m., 3 p.m., 6p.m.). Those messages produced are not ordered by scheduled time as messages for timeslot 6p.m. can be written to the queue earlier from other messages and therefore scheduled messages can be interleaved in order. Also since the volume of messages is pretty large I
can witness that address memory used is maxing out and multiple files are created on the paging directory for the queue.

My issue appears when my jms application starts to consume messages from the specified queue and though it starts to
consume data very fast at some point it blocks and becomes non responsive. When I check the broker's logs I can see the
following:

```
2021-03-31 15:26:03,520 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalMeasure] Component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl 
is expired on path 3: java.lang.Exception: entered
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalMeasure.enterCritical(CriticalMeasure.java:56) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalComponentImpl.enterCritical(CriticalComponentImpl.java:52) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.addConsumer(QueueImpl.java:1403) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl.<init>(ServerConsumerImpl.java:262) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.createConsumer(ServerSessionImpl.java:569) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.slowPacketHandler(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:328) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.onMessagePacket(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:292) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.Actor.doTask(Actor.java:33) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_262]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_262]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
2021-03-31 15:26:03,525 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224079: The process for the virtual machine will be killed, as component 
QueueImpl[name=my-queue, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=f3fddf74-9212-11eb-9a18-005056b570b4], 
temp=false]@5a4be15a is not responsive 
2021-03-31 15:26:03,980 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222199: Thread dump: **********
```

The broker halts and the slave broker becomes alive but the messages scheduled are still hanging on the queue.
When restarting the master broker I can see some logs like these below

```
2021-03-31 15:59:41,810 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session f558ac8f-9220-11eb-98a4-005056b5d5f6
2021-03-31 15:59:41,814 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222066: Reattach request from /ip-app:52922 failed as there is no confirmationWindowSize configured, which may be      ok for your system
2021-03-31 16:01:14,163 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222172: Queue my-queue was busy for more than 10,000 milliseconds. There are possibly consumers hanging      on a network operation
2021-03-31 16:01:14,163 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222144: Queue could not finish waiting executors. Try increasing the thread pool size
```

Taking a look at cpu and memory metrics I do not see anything unusual since CPU at the time of consuming is less than 50% of the max load and memory of the broker host is also at the same levels (60% used). I/O is rather insignificant, but what may be helpful is that the number of blocking threads has a sharp increase just before that error (0 -> 40). Also heap memory is maxed out but I do not see any GC out of the ordinary as far as I can tell.

This figure is after reproducing it for messages scheduled to leave at 2:30p.m.
Also part of thread dump showing blocked and timed_waiting threads

```
"Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@2a54a73f)" Id=44 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10e20f4f
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10e20f4f
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:112)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)


"Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@2a54a73f)" Id=43 BLOCKED on org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c owned by "Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)" Id=24
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.RefsOperation.afterCommit(RefsOperation.java:182)
        -  blocked on org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl.afterCommit(TransactionImpl.java:579)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl@26fb9cb9
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl.access$100(TransactionImpl.java:40)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl$2.done(TransactionImpl.java:322)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.OperationContextImpl$1.run(OperationContextImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$$Lambda$30/1259174396.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

        Number of locked synchronizers = 1
        - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@535779e4

"Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)" Id=24 RUNNABLE
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.open(NIOSequentialFile.java:143)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.open(NIOSequentialFile.java:98)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile@520b145f
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageReader.openPage(PageReader.java:114)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageReader.getMessage(PageReader.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageReader.getMessage(PageReader.java:105)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageReader@669a8420
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageCursorProviderImpl.getMessage(PageCursorProviderImpl.java:151)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageSubscriptionImpl.queryMessage(PageSubscriptionImpl.java:634)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl.getPagedMessage(PagedReferenceImpl.java:132)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl@3bfc8d39
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl.getMessage(PagedReferenceImpl.java:99)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl.getMessageMemoryEstimate(PagedReferenceImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.internalAddHead(QueueImpl.java:2839)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.addHead(QueueImpl.java:1102)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.addHead(QueueImpl.java:1138)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ScheduledDeliveryHandlerImpl$ScheduledDeliveryRunnable.run(ScheduledDeliveryHandlerImpl.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

        Number of locked synchronizers = 1
        - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@11f0a5a1
```

Note also that I did try increasing the memory resources on the broker so as to avoid triggering paging messages on disk and doing so made the problem disappear, but since my message volume is going to be erratic I do not see that as a long term solution.

Can you give me any pointers how to resolve this issue? How can I cope with large volumes of paged data stored in the broker that need
to be released at large chunks to consumers ?

Edit: After increasing number of scheduled threads

After using an increased number of scheduled threads critical analyzer did not terminate the broker but I got constant warnings like the ones below

```
2021-04-14 17:48:26,818 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 4606893a-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,818 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 460eedac-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,818 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 460eedac-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,818 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 46194def-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 46194def-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 4620ef13-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 4620ef13-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 46289036-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 46289036-9d2b-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 562d6a93-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 562d6a93-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 56324c96-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,819 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 56324c96-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:48:26,838 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222066: Reattach request from /my-host:47392 failed as there is no confirmationWindowSize configured, which may be ok for your system
2021-04-14 17:48:26,840 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222066: Reattach request from /my-host:47392 failed as there is no confirmationWindowSize configured, which may be ok for your system
2021-04-14 17:48:26,855 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222066: Reattach request from /my-host:47392 failed as there is no confirmationWindowSize configured, which may be ok for your system
2021-04-14 17:48:26,864 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222066: Reattach request from /my-host:47392 failed as there is no confirmationWindowSize configured, which may be ok for your system
2021-04-14 17:49:26,804 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 82978142-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
2021-04-14 17:49:26,804 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 82978142-9d30-11eb-9b31-005056b5d5f6
```

And traffic on my consumer side had spike and dips as shown in the following figure [image]

which essentially crippled throughput. Note that more than 80% percent of the messages were already in memory and only a small portion was paged on disk.

Comment: Hi Justin I updated my answer with more details that will hopefully help.

Comment: How many threads are blocked on `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c`?

Comment: It depends but usually around 30, close to the number shown in the attached figure

Comment: What thread is actually holding the lock on the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl@64e9ee3c`?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but I edited question to include thread 3 with id=24 which as I understand holds the lock

Answer (score 1):

I think the two most important things for your use-case are going to be:

- Avoid paging. Paging is a palliative measure meant to be used as a last resort to keep the broker functioning. If at all possible you should configure your broker to handle your load without paging (e.g. acquire more RAM, allocate more heap). It's worth noting that the broker is not designed like a database. It is designed for messages to *flow through* it. It can certainly buffer messages (potentially millions depending on the configuration & hardware) but when its forced to page the performance will drop substantially simply because disk is orders of magnitude slower than RAM.
- Increase [`scheduled-thread-pool-max-size`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/thread-pooling.html#server-scheduled-thread-pool). Dumping this many scheduled messages on the broker is going to put tremendous pressure on the scheduled thread pool. The default size is only `5`. I suggest you increase that until you stop seeing performance benefits.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the response, regarding paging, I need to be able rely on it, in some corner cases when it is possible to have a massive amount of scheduled messages. Now increasing scheduled-thread-pool-max-size (e.g to 20) avoids thread dumps on master server, but I can see a loop of consumer connections failing (AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources ) and then trying to reattach. On consumer side I can see something similar to a saw-tooth pattern where some requests are consumed then connection to the broker is dropped and more of the same, which cripples throughput.

Comment: To be clear, you *can* rely on paging to do what it was designed to do. I just wanted to point out it's not designed to be used all the time. It is a palliative to be used as a last resort.

Comment: Regarding the client disconnects...Can you elaborate on the client and server conditions when you observe this behavior? It may be worth marking this question as answered and creating a new question for this specific problem. Hashing stuff like this out in the comments is not ideal by any means.

Comment: Ok you are right I should open a new question for this (if I cannot find out what causes it), but I was just a brief answer regarding the effect of applying your suggestions. I do consider them helpful and probably valuable to others having similar problems but unfortunately I need to dig out further and see the root of my issue.

Comment: Thanks Justin for taking interest, I did edit my question to include the latest information after increasing scheduled-thread-pool-size as suggested